# API for mathematical calculations on the cloud

Tags: api, math

Is there any service that provide a public API to perform mathematical calculations (such as linear algebra decompositions etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a Java Google Appengine based service here [mobmath.appspot.com](http://mobmath.appspot.com/). You can find the project page here: [Symja project](http://code.google.com/p/symja/). The Linear Algebra functions are implemented with the commons math library ([Examples](http://code.google.com/p/symja/wiki/UsedLibraries)).

There exist a project for Python here: [Sympy project](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) the online interface can be found here: [live.sympy.org](http://live.sympy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) has an [API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/webserviceapi.html), but it [isn't free](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/pricing.html) to use.

Comment: URL for information about the web service API: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/webserviceapi.html. It isn't free though, but that wasn't specified.